# angularjs ng-click handling by child directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have 'market' directive:

```
angular
.module('myModule')
.directive('market', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: '<div outcome="outcome" ng-click="onOutcomeClick()" ng-repeat="outcome in market.Outcomes">{{outcome.Odd}}</div>', 
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.market = {
                Outcomes: [
                    { Odd: 1 },
                    { Odd: 2 },
                    { Odd: 3 },
                    { Odd: 4 },
                    { Odd: 5 },
                ]
            };
        }],
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        }
    }
}]);
```

which contains many 'outcome' directives:

```
angular
.module('myModule')
.directive('outcome', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            outcome: '='
        },
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.onOutcomeClick = function () {
                console.log($scope.outcome.Odd);
            };
        }],
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        }
    }
}]);
```

When I click on "outcome", it seems that angular looks for "onOutcomeClick" in "market" directive, but not in "outcome" directive.
How to force angular to call "onOutcomeClick" from "outcome" directive (scope in "outcome" directive must be isolated)

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/dgjcf41d/5/
I expect to see alert in example, but fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is you don't have to declare an `ng-click` directive inside your `market` directive, you can add the click event handler yourself inside the `outcome` directive.

**[FORKED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ryeballar/mpho586v/)**

**Javascript**

*Market directive*

```
// remove the `ng-click` directive
.directive('market', [function () {
  return {
     // ....
     template: '<div outcome="outcome" ng-repeat="outcome in market.Outcomes">{{outcome.Odd}}'</div>
     // ...
  };
});
```

*Outcome directive*

```
.directive('outcome', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            outcome: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.on('click', function() {
                alert('outcome clicked: ' + scope.outcome.Odd);
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You've defined the `ngClick` on the `market` directive. Each `outcome` directive has an isolated scope (which is a **child** of the `market` scope). that's why `ngClick` looks for `onOutcomeClick` in the `market`'s scope.

Define a template for the `outcome` directive, and put the `ngClick` there.

[A working forked demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yw0bddLL/1/):

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
    .controller('myController', [function () { }])
    .directive('market', [function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            template: '<div outcome="outcome" ng-repeat="outcome in market.Outcomes"><outcome outcome=outcome>{{outcome.Odd}}</outcome></div>', 
            controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
                $scope.market = {
                    Outcomes: [
                        { Odd: 1 },
                        { Odd: 2 },
                        { Odd: 3 },
                        { Odd: 4 },
                        { Odd: 5 },
                    ]
                };
            }]
        }
    }])
    .directive('outcome', [function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<div ng-click="onOutcomeClick()" ng-transclude></div>',
            transclude: true,
            scope: {
                outcome: '='
            },
            controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
                $scope.onOutcomeClick = function () {
                    alert('outcome clicked: ' + $scope.outcome.Odd);
                };
            }]
        }
    }]);
```